# ssh-copy-id to a tcsh on Solaris?

Tags: ssh, openssh, solaris, ssh-keys, tcsh

Im trying to copy a public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on a Solaris server. It fails with this error message:

```
$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub <USER>@<HOST>
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
<USER>@<HOST>'s password: <PASSWORD>
sh: test: argument expected
```

Seems like this is a problem with Solaris default tcsh shell. Is there a way to either make this work or make ssh-copy-id use bash?

Comment: Can you tell if the `sh: test: argument expected` error message is generated locally or from the remote server?

Comment: How would I figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

tcsh is by no means the "default" shell for SunOS/Solaris.

/bin/sh is the default shell for Solaris 10 and down.
/bin/bash is the default shell for Solaris 11 forward.

The script will work properly with /bin/ksh if you remove the "local" command from in front of several variable inits.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "remove the "local" command from in front of several variable inits"?

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty old but in case anyone stumbles on it this is the fix to the ssh-copy-id to work when copying to Solaris 10 and older - put double quotes around this expression inside ssh-copy-id script:

```
[ -z "\`tail -1c ${AUTH_KEY_FILE} 2>/dev/null\`" ]
```